When the character stops, look in the opposite direction
Looking at the debug log, the rb.velocity.x value is 1.262177E when moving to the left and stopping, and -1.262177E when moving to the right and stopping.
https://youtube.com/shorts/o3YiXQMJZr4?feature=share
Make the rb.velocity.x value be recognized as 0 when it falls below a certain level.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems there may be a misunderstanding of the purpose of this site. This is a place where you can post your code questions, usually with specific details, including code you've written so far and what errors you're running into. Currently this reads as a demand for us to write your code for you. Please learn how to produce a minimal reproducible example, not just posting a YouTube video for us to watch and expect us to write code for you. Good luck!

@AustinDuling no, I do think this is a question - OP correct me if I'm wrong but as I understand you wanted to ask: Even when (apparently) fully stopped, the rb.velocity.x remains a very small value like e.g. 1.262177E-7 but you want to compare to/check for 0 which fails due to this inaccuracy

In general you can't directly compare float using == due to precision - more information on that see Is floating-point math broken?. And even more if physics is involved.
rather use
if(Mathf.Apprimately(0f, rb.velicty.x))
{
    ...
}

Mathf.Approximately as the name suggests uses a reduced approximate precision. It basically equals (more or less - see source code)
if(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
{
    ...
}

If even that fails you can use a wider threshold and do e.g.
if(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) <= YOUR_THRESHOLD)
{
    ...
}

